# IdentityServer: How to give option to user with 'Retry Url' which redirects to Client Link

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver3, identityserver4

Using IdentityServer 4 for authentication which work with different clients, that support OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 protocols for AAD authentication

In scenario, if there is an error before Login or after Login (authentication)
User is redirected to Home\Error, default exception middlerware handler. Here I want to provide user with 'Retry Url' which redirects to Client link.

Appreciate if any body can suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

In Account Controller Login() you can get the return_url from the model(check LoginViewModel). Just validate this return_url and Redirect the user, it will take it to the client. You can also fetch the **redirect_uri** from return_url which have the client info - if thats what you are looking for!

You can always pass the return_url to error view and inject it in a hyperlink where user can click to go back to the client.